# Peach leaves drying up and falling off

Tags: fruit-trees, peaches

I just bought a peach tree about a little over a week ago. It's still in the container as I haven't had a chance to plant it. It seemed fine when I got it, but in the time I've had it the leaves have started drying up and the edges flaking of or leaves completely falling off.

The spot where I have it is currently on a raised deck where it is pretty windy. It doesn't get terribly cold though. Could the wind cause this?

I got the tree from Costco so it probably had been indoors for a bit. Could it be that it's not acclimated to the sun?

I'm in the San Francisco bay area, in the hills. It is a bit cool here, but not extreme. Days lately have been in the 80s and evenings in the 60s maybe.

There was some pest damage to the leaves (holes in the leaves) when I bought it.

Here are some photos of the leaves.

[image]
[image]